# CardView with buttons without using RecyclerView - Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use a CardView as a container for a menu; the card is populated with buttons. Is it possible to implement a click listener on each button without using a RecyclerView?

Applying a click listener on the buttons during creation, before being added to CardView and after being added to CardView is not working. Only the card itself remains clickable

Comment: put some code so we can help

Comment: Yes,
You can use cardview as menu item but you should use layout instead of menu.
You need to implement individual click for them.

Comment: Once check with this : http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2014/01/drawerlayout-with-custom-layoutview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example , two buttons are added on a cardview , where each view has separate click listener. You can try this-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Button btn_first, btn_second;
    CardView cardView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_first = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_first);
        btn_second = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_second);
        btn_first.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_second.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_first:
                Toast.makeText(this, "First Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_second:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Second Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.cardview:
                Toast.makeText(this, "CardView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.module.taman.splash.mvp.SplashActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"
            android:text="Click me !!" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Code

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "ButtonClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "card clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```